# ionic 3 capacitor return file paths from document directory

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, capacitor

Ionic 3 capacitor on ios.

I have stored jpeg files in the  AppData Documents directory. Now I want to display the images. The images are displayed in the HTML with 
     `img src="{{image2}}"` ( one option )

This is my working code, it returns the actual path to the file ( based in part on Josh Morony 'ionic capacitor photo save', in part on capacitor source code FileSystem API) :

```
fileName1 = "photo2.jpeg";

Filesystem.getUri({
  directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data,
  path: fileName1
}).then((result) => {
  this.image1 = result.uri.replace('file://', '_capacitor_');
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

fileName2 = "photo2.jpeg";

   Filesystem.getUri({
  directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data,
  path: fileName2
}).then((result) => {
  this.image2 = result.uri.replace('file://', '_capacitor_');
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});


fileName3 = "photo3.jpeg";

   Filesystem.getUri({
  directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data,
  path: fileName3
}).then((result) => {
  this.image3 = result.uri.replace('file://', '_capacitor_');
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

example of path returned in this.image: *capacitor*/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1C408C3C- 
  DB30-47C1-3416-6FB2697DC7AF/Documents/photo2.jpeg

I have 20 photos in the Documents directory; the names of the photos in an `array = ["photo1.jpeg","photo2.jpeg","photo3.jpeg"," ...];`

I can repeat the code above 20 times and get 20 paths, but I would like to refactor the code so that the code returns an array of 20 paths. I do not know how to achieve that in ionic 3.